# A lightweight free tool to convert SVG to PNG or JPG, that doesn't require Homebrew

Tags: software-recommendation, file-conversion

I need a free tool to convert SVG images to PNG or JPG. I cannot use Homebrew, because this is a company computer and Homebrew is against the company policy. I'd like a GUI tool, but that isn't mandatory.

### Requirements

1. runs on Monterey (online tools are also fine, but see below)
2. free (preferably OS, but not necessarily)
3. converts from SVG to JPG/PNG and it allows resizing by keeping the original image aspect ratio.
4. lightweight, both in terms of disk space and CPU usage
5. (nice to have) a GUI. I can definitely live without one, as long as the CLI tool supports requirement 3 (resize by keeping the original aspect ratio), or at least it can tell me the aspect ratio of the original SVG image, so that I can calculate a new width & height manually

### What I tried so far

- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) works really well and it's free, but at about 600 Mb it's not exactly lightweight. Of course this makes sense, since it features so much more than just conversion to bitmap formats with automatic resize, but I don't need the other features.
- https://image.online-convert.com/convert/svg-to-png is an online tool that supports converting from SVG to PNG. However, there doesn't seem to be an option to change just width and preserve aspect ratio. I could do the calculation by hand, **if** the tool allowed to see the size of the original SVG image, but since it doesn't, it all becomes very cumbersome.

Comment: If it is ti run on a company's machine ask the company what tool you canuse

Comment: Inkscape is probably your best option. 600Mb isn't that massive. However, if this is a company computer for commercial work, why only free software? Will your company not pay for the software you need to do your job?

Comment: *imagemagick* or *graphicsmagick* - your search engine will find them for you.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark imagemagick seems to be the perfect tool, however it requires Homebrew https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark graphicsmagick doesn't have MacOS binaries https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/1.3.36/

Comment: Oh dear.  MacPorts lists GraphicsMagick so I just assumed that there would be Mac binaries available.  And yes, I'm not suggesting that MacPorts is the solution to the 'no Homebrew rule'.  When I have a need (as opposed to a wish) to have a non-standard piece of software installed on my company MBP I get the company sys admin to do it.  Personally I think that's the way you should be going too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark most stuff that doesn't require `sudo` access is allowed (Homebrew is specifically_ not_ allowed, not sure if because of `sudo` or whatever).   Isn't there a lightweight version of Inkscape? Anyway, for non-standard stuff, usually I give my requirements and a couple proposals, and then a workflow starts. So I'd need those two proposals.

Comment: *Isn't there a lightweight version of Inkscape?* I don't know, but it seems irrelevant anyway, you're not looking for a drawing tool are you?  Aren't you just looking for file converter to read SVGs and write JPEGs or PNGs?  As to presenting your two proposals, that's easy, you just ask for ImageMagick and for Inkscape and be happy whichever one gets installed?  If they need to install Homebrew to install one of them, well, they can always disable it after they have set things up.